# How can I increase the json_encode depth limit

Tags: php, json

How can I set the maximum depth limit to unlimited for json_encode function in PHP?

My problem is;

```
$array = 
[
    [
       [
          ['hello'],
       ],
    ],
];
```

Json_encode function returns false when I add more than 3 arrays multidimensionally. I wanna remove this limit. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/566f4af4ef99c08289f2d8b4118a56d103dca2ee) work for you on your own PHP installation? Because it works fine on a normal PHP installation

Comment: I don't run into a depth limit. I increased it to 6 levels and it still works.

Comment: I can run this script my localhost. But I can't use on hosting.

Comment: What does `echo json_last_error_msg();` show?

Comment: `json_encode()` has a 3rd argument `$depth` that specifies the depth limit. It defaults to 512.

Comment: @Barmar "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Comment: That has nothing to do with depth, it means there are invalid characters in the string.

Comment: Use the `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` or `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE` flags.

Comment: @Barmar *embarassed* - I'm doing 3 things at once.

Comment: Thanks man! You really helped me!

Answer (score -2):

The `json_encode` function accepts a `depth` parameter: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode

```php
<?php
$array = 
[
    [
       [
          ['hello'],
       ],
    ],
];

$text = json_encode($array, 8);
?>
```

Comment: Since the default is 512, this won't fix the problem. And the error message is not about the depth.

Comment: @Barmar This answers the question being asked. I see the discussion in the comments, the question should be updated accordingly.

Comment: It would only answer the question being asked if his arrays were nested more than 512 levels.

Comment: That is a good idea. That was not obvious to me however. OP said "I can run this script my localhost. But I can't use on hosting." so it could have been a limitation on the host behalf.